# Atualizar RecyclerView a partir de outra Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Tenho a seguinte classe

```
    public class FavoriteListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.favorite_item, parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return favoriteVideos.size();
    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        favoriteVideos.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(FavoriteVideo favoriteVideo){
        favoriteVideos.add(favoriteVideo);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
        private TextView mVideoTitleTextView;
        private TextView mVideoTimeTextView;
        private Context mContext;
        String videoURL;
        String videoName;
        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            mVideoTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favoriteVideoTitleTextView);
            //mVideoTimeTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoTimeTextView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            return false;
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            mVideoTitleTextView.setText(favoriteVideos.get(position).getName());
            //mVideoTimeTextView.setText(Topic.list_time_videos[position]);
            videoName = favoriteVideos.get(position).getName();
            videoURL = favoriteVideos.get(position).getUrl();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent videoIntent;
            if (getVideoOrigin(videoURL).equals("youtube")) {
                videoIntent = new Intent(mContext, YoutubePlayerActivity.class);
            } else {
                videoIntent = new Intent(mContext, VideoActivity.class);
            }
            videoIntent.putExtra("videoURL", videoURL.split(("/"))[videoURL.split(("/")).length - 1]);
            videoIntent.putExtra("videoName", videoName);

            mContext.startActivity(videoIntent);
        }

        private String getVideoOrigin(String video) {
            if (video.contains("youtube")) {
                return "youtube";
            } else {
                return "vimeo";
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.favorites));
            menu.add(0, view.getId(), 0, mContext.getString(R.string.remove_from_favorites)).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.confirmation))
                    .setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(mContext);
                            dataSource.deleteFavoriteVideo(videoURL);
                            delete(getAdapterPosition());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.removed_favorite_video), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Preciso conseguir atualizar este recycler view, a partir do click de um botão em uma outra activity.

Já tentei utilizar o `notifyDataSetChanged();`, mas este só funciona se a atualização ocorrer dentro do RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

O método mais fácil é usando o [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).
O próprio nome já diz...É um delivery de eventos (de qualquer lugar para qualquer lugar).

É só por `EventBus.getDefault.register(this);` no construtor do recyclerview e depois criar um método qualquer (dentro ainda do recyclerview) que atualize a lista. Adicione o anottation @Subscribe em cima do método...
Da activity, chame `EventBus.getDefault.post(new ClasseDeEvento(listagem));`(evidentemente num clique de botão, por exemplo)
Essa ClasseDeEvento é uma classe qualquer que você deve criar e passar no post do EventBus.Não se esqueça de setar o novo arraylist dentro dessa classe..... Para chamar o método do recyclerView, o método dele deve RECEBER do tipo ClasseDeEvento.

Exemplo:
 (isso fica no RV)

```
@Subscribe
public void onEventAtualizarLista(ClasseDeEvento cde){
this.listagem = cde.getListagem();
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Simples e magicamente o método com @Subscribe e que recebe do mesmo tipo no parâmetro vai ser chamado automaticamente após o post...

Comment: Uma biblioteca muito boa para trabalhar com os **EventBus** é a **otto** da **square**.

Referencia:
http://square.github.io/otto/